# empty line created at the top of my text file python

Tags: python, text-files

```
myfile = open('curr_data.txt', 'w')
for row in stat_table.find_all('tr'):           
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        myfile.write(cell.text + ',')
    myfile.write("\n")
```

When it writes to the text file it adds a empty line at the top of the text file. It is for some reason caused by the "\n" because when i remove it then there is no empty line.

It is as if `myfile.write("\n")` gets executed before `myfile.write(cell.text + ',')`

My output looks like

```
                BLANK LINE HERE
1#BitcoinBTC#ZAR108,103.18#+0.16%#ZAR2.0T#Trade#
2#EthereumETH#ZAR2,148.71#+0.03%#ZAR233.8B#Trade#
3#XRPXRP#ZAR3.25#+2.40%#ZAR140.6B#Trade#
4#Bitcoin CashBCH#ZAR3,093.58#-0.92%#ZAR56.2B#Trade#
5#LitecoinLTC#ZAR652.31#-1.14%#ZAR41.6B#Trade#
```

Where i want it to look like

```
1#BitcoinBTC#ZAR108,103.18#+0.16%#ZAR2.0T#Trade#
2#EthereumETH#ZAR2,148.71#+0.03%#ZAR233.8B#Trade#
3#XRPXRP#ZAR3.25#+2.40%#ZAR140.6B#Trade#
4#Bitcoin CashBCH#ZAR3,093.58#-0.92%#ZAR56.2B#Trade#
5#LitecoinLTC#ZAR652.31#-1.14%#ZAR41.6B#Trade#
```

Comment: does `stat_table` have a row in it without any cells? Normally a html table has a beginning row with headers (`th`)

Comment: Yes I see now that the table has a row in the table header which doesn't have any td's. Is there a way that I can then skip the first row in the loop ? @Sayse

Comment: Give a example but do not post original information in any input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a html table has a beginning row with headers (`th`).

If you're guarranteed to always have a row with a table header then you can start your outer loop from the first index onwards with slicing.

```
for row in stat_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
```

Answer (score 0):

just check if any `row.find_all('td')` is returning an empty list (ie `tr` without `td`), if empty list avoid `myfile.write("\n")`

```
myfile = open('curr_data.txt', 'w')
for row in stat_table.find_all('tr'): 
    data = row.find_all('td')
    if data:        
        for cell in data:
            myfile.write(cell.text + ',')
        myfile.write("\n")
```